# Laravel Dusk selector for child element using index

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I am developing a Web application using Laravel framework. I am using Nova as my admin panel. What I am doing now is that I am running Dusk/Browser Unit Test on my Nova application panel. I am currently testing on an index table.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Basic I can select the `<tr>` tag using the dusk selector since there is a dusk selector defined on each row. But the issue is that I want to retrieve each td content inside that row. Now I can retrieve the content of tr like this

```
$browser->text('@1-row ');
```

But I like to retrieve each td content. For example something like this.

```
The first td content inside the first row.
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try use [scoping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/dusk#scoping-selectors) ?

```
 $browser->with('@1-row', function ($tr) {
     $tr->text('td:first-child');
 });
```